# Error with ConsensusClusterPlus function and subsampling by pFeature parameter

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

The following function returns an error which I am unable to resolve.

```
pl.eset <- matrix(runif(50*30), nrow=50, ncol=30)
ConsensusClusterPlus::ConsensusClusterPlus(pl.eset, pFeature = 0.50, reps = 500,distance = "euclidean", clusterAlg = "km",verbose = F)
```

Of which pl.eset is a 50x30 matrix with numeric values, without any NAs.

When running the piece of code, it returns the following error:

```
Error in if (is.na(sample_x$submat)) { : the condition has length > 1
```

The error has something to do with the subsampling by pFeature. When pFeature = 1 then the error doesn't show up.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You probably already found the answer, but I had this issue too, and couldn't find anything except your question.

The problem is this line in the function ccRun, which is called within ConsensusClusterPlus():

```
if ( is.na( sample_x$submat ) ) {
        stop( "error submat is NA" )
      }
```

This is only run if you:

- Provide a data matrix, not a distance matrix
- Set `method='km'`
- Give a value for pFeature, and this value is not 1

  OR Set `pFeature=1` and give a value for weightsFeature

so it isn't a problem if `pFeature=1` and you don't give weights.

`sample_x$submat` is a subset of the data you provided for clustering generated for a given iteration. Therefore `is.na(sample_x$submat)` returns a boolean matrix rather than single value, hence the error message 'condition has length > 1'

I think that this was intended to stop the run if any values within `sample_x$submat = NA`, but instead it stops the whole thing no matter what the values in sample_x$submat.

I fixed it by copying the source code from here: https://rdrr.io/bioc/ConsensusClusterPlus/src/R/ConsensusClusterPlus.R

Then replacing the if statement in question (Line 410) with:

```
if ( sum(is.na( sample_x$submat ))>0 ) {
        stop( "error submat is NA" )
      }
```

and sourcing this script instead of loading the ConsensusClusterPlus package.